# Code coverage for border cases that are not assigned to separate lines

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, eclemma

I'm using Eclemma in Eclipse to show me the test coverage for my classes. But even if the line and branch coverage are both 100%, there can be still cases that are not covered by unit tests.

Example:

```
public double myCos(double angle) {
    return Math.cos(angle);
}
```

If I call this method with the argument Math.PI from my test class, the line, branch and path coverage will be 100%, but with this approach I haven't tested all relevant border cases, like Math.cos(Math.PI * 0.5), Math.cos(0), Math.cos(Math.PI * 1.5) etc.

The only way that I know to enforce code coverage for such cases, is writing the code in the following way:

```
public double myCos(double angle) {
    if (angle == Math.PI) {
        //Don't do anything. This is only for the coverage tool to enforce
        //border case testing to achieve 100% coverage
    }
    //...other border cases
    return Math.cos(angle);
}
```

This way, the test code has to go through the border cases to achieve 100% branch coverage.

This is obviously not the best way to implement the method. What are alternatives to tackle the problem? Are there any annotations in code coverage tools to tag border cases in the more convinient way? What are, generally, best practices to handle my example?

Answer (score 2):

From a line/condition coverage perspective, there is nothing wrong. Your code has a single line and only one branch, which both are covered. 
From testing perspective, you assume the correctness of `Math.cos()` and your code works fine in that regard, I'd say that is fine.

But those coverage analyzers are rather dumb tools, they don't tell you, whether you've tested the right thing, therefore you need to actually use your brain and design proper test cases that define the constraints of your problem domain.

```
myCos(double angle) {
   return Math.cos(angle);  
}
```

is the same for input `PI` as

```
myCos(double angle) {
   return -1;
}
```

Nevertheless, for some scenarios you have some help with border cases, using a technique called Mutation Testing. But this doesn't tell you as well if you're implemented the right requirement.

In case you want to implement an alternative to `Math.cos()`, and your assumption is, that Math.cos() is correct, you could actually use it to verify the correctness of your implementation, iterating from 0 to 2*PI and compare the values of your implementation with that of `Math.cos()`.

Comment: I was hoping for some annotations telling the test coverage tool that border cases have to be tested in order to achieve full coverage. Something like @Testcase(angle=0) in my case. Eclemma would only mark the method as covered if at least one of the test executions has used alpha parameter with the argument zero.

Comment: but then you're looking for kind of semantic coverage, but line/condition coverage is not capable of doing this. Using Mutation Testing might reveal missing edge cases, but not in this case as Math.cos() relies on native methods which can not be mutated.

Comment: Mutation testing is a good keyword. Will have a look at it. Thanks.